# Why does Location.distanceBetween throw an Exception for the result parameter?

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

Why does`Location.distanceBetween` throw an Exception with the following example:

```
Location.distanceBetween(51.5175431381974,-0.1501073187713473, 51.5173695544231, -0.15127676190184, results);
```

I checked same positioning [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) and the distance was reported as 0.08319 km and I'm not sure why it throws the Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: results is null or has length < 1
```

Comment: Where is your defintion of results? How does it look like?

Comment: What's `results`? And what's the exception (seems an obvious thing to include :(

Comment: this is a float array of length zero - and zero < 1

You have to declare it to be of length 1, 2 or 3 - depending on the values you want to have stored in.

Comment: @fkerber @ Marcin Czech how to declare that ?

Comment: i got it.... results = new float[3];

Answer (score 13, accepted):

your results variable needs to be initalized to an array of floats with length > 0.  The spots in this array are filled with the result of the calculation.

Comment: For anyone looking, the declaration for results should be
float[] results = new float[3];